# Access Form properties into a static method C#

Tags: c#

I would like to disable my form when I launch a process, and enable my Form when I exit the same process. 
The thing is, when I try to enable it, `Supervision` into the new `EventHandler` is `null`.

All of this is into a static method.

If anybody have an idea with this problem, I'll be really grateful :)

Here is my code :

```
Process p = new Process();                //I create my process
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = dico[btn.Name];

p.Exited += new EventHandler((_, args) =>     //When the process is exited, I try to enable my Form but Supervision is null
{
     Supervision.ActiveForm.Enabled = true;   //"Supervision" is the name of my form
});
p.Start();

Supervision.ActiveForm.Enabled = false; //I disable my Form when the process is launch
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Did you try to debug? Is it called? What is the value when it's called? Perhaps you want to capture active form into local variable?

Comment: The question makes very little sense.  Surely the real problem is that the Exited event handler runs on a worker thread so you are not allowed to set the Enabled property.  Trivially solved by setting the Process.SynchronizingObject property.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes I tried to debug, and it's like Hans Passant said, I'm not allowed to use the Form properties, he's not known into the EventHandler (NullReferenceException for Supervision). I'll try to set the Process.SynchronizingObject property !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find a way to do what I wanted :

In the same function, I make this :

```
Form form = new Form();
form = Supervision.ActiveForm;
```

And into the Exited EventHandler, I set the Enabled property :

```
form.Enabled = true;
```

I don't know if it's the good way to do this but it's work !

Thanks for your support !

Comment: Thats a good solution. Basically you store a reference to the current active form, disable it and after the process exited you enable the same form again without relying on `ActiveForm` which could change anyway and is propably null because your form does not have the focus anymore. But you should not create a new Form instance just to reassign it, just do `Form form = Supervision.ActiveForm;`

Comment: Yeah that's right ! I didn't pay attention but it's better like you said !
Thanks for the tip and the explication !